# java regular expression matching with arithmetic operation

Tags: java, regex

I am implementing calculator with java.

So, I tried this:

If end of the string is not '+', '-', '*', '/', or '(', then add '+' at the end of the string.

So, I tried following code (assume that variable `s` is `12345+`):

```
if(!s.matches("[-(+*/]$"))
   s+="+";
```

But, the if statement(`s.matches("[-(+-*/]$")`) does not return `true`, am I wrong?? It works on linux's bash shell well.

Comment: `String#matches` requires a full string match. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912978/java-regex-pattern-that-matches-in-any-online-tester-but-doesnt-in-eclipse

Comment: Also, `-` has special meaning inside a character class (`[]`), so `+-*` means all characters from `+` to `*` and since `+` is ASCII 43 and `*` is ASCII 42, that's an inverted range, and will either fail or match nothing.

Comment: ah, sorry my mistake, `[-+*/]$` doesn't work too

Comment: Why not just do it a proper java way without regex?

Comment: @Wiktro Stribizew Then, Can't it be possible with other regex??

Comment: @redFIVE Why is a non-regex way more proper than regex? It would definitely require a lot more code that using regex, so regex is "cleaner" / more concise.

Comment: @redFIVE  dummy-looking code is made because of many if statements

Comment: @Andreas, maybe not cleaner, but certainly less troubleshooting required.

Comment: @A.Cho Sure it's possible. Drop the anchor (`$`) since it's meaningless when using `matches()`, and make it `".*[-(+*/]"`

Comment: @Andreas: Or `"(?s).*[-(+*/]"` (if there can be a newline, but I guess there is not)

Comment: @redFIVE I disagree. A non-regex way would be to get the last character `x.charAt(x.length()-1)` and compare that to the 5 characters under consideration. The pitfall there is the empty string, so it is no less error-prone than regex.