# Regext do not work in java but it does inr egex check

Tags: java, regex

Hello I have a simple regex which should check if string ends with milliseconds (DOT, NUMBER, NUMBER, NUMBER, END OF STRING)

I set regex .\d{3}

and check it in several ways and this always returns false (even if there is  pattern on the end):

[image]

Any idea whay this does not work?
It works well on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you declare it as `"\\.\\d+$"`? Is the `$` expected to match end of string or line? Also, use `.find()`, not `matches()`.

Comment: As Wiktor said, double escape is the key.

Comment: yes, you can see it on image at end of line 6

Comment: private final static String REGEX_ENDS_WITH_MILLISECONDS = "\\.\\d{3}$";

Comment: That means the only problem is that you use `matches()` instead of `find()`, so, the question is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912978/java-regex-pattern-that-matches-in-any-online-tester-but-doesnt-in-eclipse.

Comment: if part is messed up a bit cause I try to find out why does not work :D it sensslessatm :)

Comment: And if you match question as EXACT DUPLICATE could you add link to  other ticked instead to your name?

Comment: Revo you are wrong, Wiktor provided link to solution... matches check for whole string find it search if pattern is present in string...

Comment: Although you had one more misunderstanding to be solved, I wasn't wrong about what I have said.